# Influx Database error when writing to history file

Tags: influxdb

I am using influxDB. when I run a command e.g. `SHOW measurements` from influx CLI I get the following Error: 
`there was an error writing history file : open : The system file cannot find the file specified`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows:

1) Create the influx.bat file as below:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET HOME=%~dp0
"%~dp0\influx.exe" %*
ENDLOCAL
```

2) save it in the same directory as influxdb executable files. 
See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yAXx.jpg)