# "error writing history file: open :" error for influxDB on every command

Tags: influxdb

I am installing and trying to set up influxDB locally. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437608/influx-database-error-when-writing-to-history-file) solution but the error(There was an error writing history file: open : The system cannot find the file specified.) shows up on nearly every command. I have tried using CREATE DATABASE Test and the error shows but when I run SHOW DATABASE the database was created. I was wondering how to fix this error.

Also, my http://localhost:8086/ shows - 404 page not found. In youtube videos ppl had web interface/GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue and found following solution:
Create batch file in the same folder as is influx.exe, name it for example influx.bat (it doesn't matter).
Add following code inside the bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET HOME=%~dp0
"%~dp0\influx.exe" %*
ENDLOCAL
```

I've found it here: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6070

Does work for me.